# Absolute .position() value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

Sometimes, when I ask for the `.position().top` value of some object, it does not return the absolute value, i.e. if some picture is added before, the `.position().top` value does not change. **How may I ask for the absolute position of an object (in this case a div)?**

Comment: @PrakharSingh, if there's no top set in css that will return empty.

Comment: @PrakharSingh I only get 'auto'

Comment: Use `offset()` instead of `position()`

Comment: @Mouser Yes, right, it works!!

Comment: Too bad I didn't post it as an answer. Give Mario the reward :)

Comment: @Mouser Sorry for that, I guess we had the same idea almost at the same time.

Comment: I shouldn't have used a comment, so no sorry here. You deserve it. Got XP enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the jquery docs:

> The .position() method allows us to retrieve the current position of
>   an element relative to the offset parent. Contrast this with
>   .offset(), which retrieves the current position relative to the
>   document.

http://api.jquery.com/position/

So use `.offset()`.